# MariaDB gives syntax error with empty near-string

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures, syntax

Im using MariaDB 10.24.8 on Linux and I'm encoutering this syntax error which has been stumping me for the last few hours:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

with this SQL-Query for creating a stored-procedure:

```
USE getranke;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_scan;

-- param scan INT: Barcode Value
-- out-param result INT: 0 = registered; 1 = DB is in inventory mode
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_scan(
    IN scan INT,
    OUT result INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE stateName TEXT;

    SELECT Name INTO stateName
    FROM StateIDs
    JOIN SystemState
        ON StateIDs.ID = SystemState.FK_StateIDs_ID
    WHERE SystemState.ID = 1;

    IF stateName = 'Inventory' THEN
        SET result = 1;
    ELSE
        SELECT scan;
        INSERT INTO Scans (FK_Drinks_barcode, when_datetime)
        VALUES (scan, NOW());
        SET result = 0;
    END IF;
END;
```

What has me especially irritated is that Rust-Rover manages to execute this query without a problem, but if I run it using the mysql/mariadb console it gives me this error. It also occurs with other front-ends like phpmyadmin.

If you need further information I'd be more than happy to provide it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has been answered many times, but I can't find such an answer, so I'm going to write one.

As the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) says,

> If you use the `mysql` client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, `mysql` itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause `mysql` to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

You do that with the `delimiter` command:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_scan
...
END
//

delimiter ;
```

With the "other front-ends like phpmyadmin" you would use their respective settings to redefine the delimiter.

Comment: Sync specified and used delimiter... Also it is not safe to use escape char as a delimiter or a part of it. I'd use double (or even triple) semicolon, it is safe close to absolutely.

Comment: thank you for the answer :) I'm a bit to pampered by things like rust-rover regarding SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the code some:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_scan (
    IN _scan INT,
    OUT _result INT )
BEGIN
    SELECT stateName = 'Inventory' INTO _result
        FROM StateIDs AS si
        JOIN SystemState AS ss
            ON si.ID = ss.FK_StateIDs_ID
        WHERE ss.ID = 1;
    IF _result
    THEN
        INSERT INTO Scans (FK_Drinks_barcode, when_datetime)
            VALUES (_scan, NOW());
    END IF;
END;

//
DELIMITER ;
```

(I like to declare arguments and local variables with a leading `_` to avoid certain puzzling errors.  No, I don't think they occurred in this  case.